# Having problems enumerating from ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am passing to my Razor view this:

```
public ActionResult NewsList()
{
  ViewBag.News = _client.GetNews(Guid.Parse(GetCookieInfo.TokenId));
  return View();
}
```

And my GetNews is this:

```
public IEnumerable<TokenNews> GetNews(Guid tokenid)
{
  var nl = from news in entities.News
         where news.TokenId == tokenid &&
               DateTime.Now > news.Expiration &&
               news.IsActive
         orderby news.OrderNumber
         select new News
                  {
                    NewsTitle = news.NewsTitle,
                    NewsBody = news.NewsBody,
                    OrderNumber = news.OrderNumber
                  };

  var newslist = new List<TokenNews>();
  foreach (var news in nl)
  {
    var nw = new TokenNews();
    nw.Body = news.NewsBody;
    nw.Title = news.NewsTitle;
    newslist.Add(nw);
  }
  return newslist;
}
```

And my TokenNews is this:

```
  [DataContract]
  public class TokenNews
  {
    private string title = string.Empty;
    private string body = string.Empty;

    public string Title {
      get { return title; }
      set { title = value; }
    }
    public string Body
    {
      get { return body; }
      set { body = value; }
    }
  }
```

My NewsList.cshtml view looks like this:

@using SuburbanCustPortal.SuburbanService

```
<br />

         @foreach (var nws in (IEnumerable<TokenNews>) ViewBag.News)
         {

           <div  class="leftdiv">
             <br/>
             <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">
               @nws.Body
             </label>
           </div>
         }
```

My problem is the `@nws.Body`. The nws is not giving me the Title or Body in my TokenNews.

It is giving me the message:

> Cannot resolve symbol body.

This has to be something I'm overlooking a hundred times but I just cannot figure it out.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

In response to Umar Farooq Khawaja:

I did as you showed and this is what happened:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `DataMember` attribute to your `TokenNews` class on the public properties. Remember to regenerate the client for the `SuburbanCustPortal.SuburbanService` service that uses the `TokenNews` class afterwards. I also used auto-generated properties rather than ones backed by private fields just to make the code a bit cleaner.

```
[DataContract]
public class TokenNews
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Body
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, try first storing `ViewBag.News` in a statically typed variable and then iterating over it using the new statically typed reference, e.g.

```
<br />
@{
    var news = (IEnumerable<TokenNews>)ViewBag.News;
}
@foreach (var item in news)
{
<div class="leftdiv">
    <br />
    <label class="sizedCustomerLabel">
        @item.Body
    </label>
</div>
}
```

Also, you can refactor the following method this way:

```
public IEnumerable<TokenNews> GetNews(Guid tokenid)
{
    var newslist = from news in entities.News
                   where news.TokenId == tokenid &&
                         DateTime.Now > news.Expiration &&
                         news.IsActive
                   orderby news.OrderNumber
                   select new TokenNews
                   {
                       Title = news.NewsTitle,
                       Body = news.NewsBody
                   };

    return newslist.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the refactor. I applied that. I did the change you suggested also, and the results are in my update. Still doesn't show it for some reason...

Comment: I just noticed that you were not applying the DataMember attribute to the public properties. I have included a change for that in my answer.

Comment: Bingo!! That was it. I knew it was something simple that I was overlooking!